# Variable is nullified before it can be used; code seems to run out of order

Tags: javascript

When I set the private variable `_callback` to `null` inside the private method `_success`, the lines `_callback(result, _secondaryCallback);`, or `_callback(result)`, do not execute because `_callback` has already been nullified by the *subsequent* line `_callback = _secondaryCallback = null;`. Whether or not it's actually accurate to say so, it seems like the code is running out of order. This is using Phonegap > iOS.

What's going on here? Why can't I call `_callback()` and then set `_callback` to null? Why is `_callback` nullified too soon?

F.Y.I., this might not be the best strategy for dealing with callbacks etc., but I'm really only interested in learning the reasons for this behavior.

```
var namespace = (function(){
    var _callback, _secondaryCallback;

    function _success(result) {             
        if (_secondaryCallback){
            _callback(result, _secondaryCallback);
        } else {
            if (_callback) _callback(result);
        }
        _callback = _secondaryCallback = null; //This prevents _callback(result, _secondaryCallback); and _callback(result); from executing
    }

    return {
        something: function(arg1, arg2){
            _callback = arg1;
            _secondaryCallback = arg2;

            callAPI({
                success: _success,
                error: function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                };
            });
        }
    };

}());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to be 100% sure as this is not a complete example showing the problem.

My wild guess however is that you're calling `something` multiple times and you're not considering that all those calls are sharing the **same variables** `_callback` and `_secondaryCallback`.

So after one calls complete all other pending calls will find the variables set to `null` once their results arrive.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

Just going by what you've shown, you are probably calling `namespace.something` multiple times and using the same 2 variables for every callback. Once it completes the `_success` function once, the 2 variables are set to null for queued up `_success` callbacks. You could solve your problem by just passing the `_callback` and `_secondaryCallback` through the function arguments.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now.